# Boolean vector indicating non-zero cells

Tags: r, csv

```
Infection 1       Infection 2      Infection 3
    6                10                  0
   10                 0                  0
    0                 0                  0
    3                 5                  0
   10                10                  1
```

I have a csv file put into R and I want to create a Boolean vector that indicates non-zero cells only.

Comment: "Boolean" is clear (in R it would be called "logical"), but what do you mean by "vector" -- how do you want to collapse the matrix to a vector? `my_data!=0` ... ???  Please indicate your desired output from this input.

Comment: It is possible to use `my_df != 0` or the more obscure `!!my_df`

Comment: Have you tried anything yet?  This isn't just a code generation site, you should try it yourself first and then after doing research and attempting a solution you can then post your work here and we can help you the rest of the way.

Comment: It is not good practise to delete a question when somebody post an answer..  Why should somebody waste their time in answering your questions if you are going to delete it?

Answer (score 1):

I'm going to guess that by `vector` you mean the `matrix` you have provided. (For future reference, a `vector` has only one dimension. It's a form of `list` of values.  A `matrix` (or `data.frame` or `data.table`) has 2 (or more) dimensions, as in X rows * Y columns).  If my guess is wrong, please update your question with the format of your desired output.

An easy way to indicate which numbers are non-zero is to use a standard comparison on the matrix:

```
# Recreate your table for this example:
infection_vals <- data.frame(c(6,10,0,3,10), c(10,0,0,5,10), c(0,0,0,0,1));

# You have column names with spaces which can be tricky in R
colnames(infection_vals) <- c("Infection 1", "Infection 2", "Infection 3");

# Output to see it
infection_vals;
>       Infection 1 Infection 2 Infection 3
>1           6          10           0
>2          10           0           0
>3           0           0           0
>4           3           5           0
>5          10          10           1

# It's easier than you think.  Just do a comparison on the table and R will
# iterate through each cell automatically and return a matrix of the same dimensions:
boolean_infection_vals <- (infection_vals > 0 | infection_vals <0);

boolean_infection_vals;
>        Infection 1 Infection 2 Infection 3
>[1,]        TRUE        TRUE       FALSE
>[2,]        TRUE       FALSE       FALSE
>[3,]       FALSE       FALSE       FALSE
>[4,]        TRUE        TRUE       FALSE
>[5,]        TRUE        TRUE        TRUE

# Check the type and class of the result
typeof(boolean_infection_vals);
>[1] "logical"

class(boolean_infection_vals);
>[1] "matrix"

# If we convert the matrix to a data.frame, we can more easily work with the columns
boolean_infection_vals_df <- as.data.frame(boolean_infection_vals);

# You can access each column of the data.frame as a vector with the $ operator.
# Quotes are needed because you have spaces in the column names
boolean_infection_vals_df$"Infection 1";
>[1]  TRUE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE
```

Good luck! :)